# Can I declare constant integers with a thousands separator in C#?

Tags: c#, constants

The [Cobra](http://cobra-language.com) programming language has a useful feature where you can use underscores in numeric literals to improve readability. For example, the following are equivalent, but the second line is easier to read:

```
x = 1000000
x = 1_000_000  # obviously 1 million
```

Is there anything equivalent for C#?

Comment: Note that this has a strong probably of coming to C# 7.

Comment: Everytime I write a large number in C#, I wish I had this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Answer as of C# 7**

Yes, this is supported in C# 7. But be aware that there's no validation that you've put the underscores in the right place:

```
// At a glance, this may look like a billion, but we accidentally missed a 0.
int x = 1_00_000_000;
```

**Answer from 2011**

No, there's nothing like that in C#. You could do:

```
const int x = 1000 * 1000;
```

but that's about as nice as it gets.

(Note that this enhancement went into [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) as well... maybe one day it will be introduced in C#.)

Comment: So you know it , looks bit cheating, how would you write 123456789

Comment: @SurjitSamra: Yes, it wouldn't help in that case - but constants are reasonably commonly multiples of other values. (e.g. "milliseconds in an hour" etc.) In that case it can often be more readable to give each constant a separate name to build them up appropriately.

Comment: My upvote if you can push CSharp team to have this feature ;)

Comment: I had thought of declaring, for example, `const int _1_000_000 = 1000000;`, but that seems more trouble than it's worth. I'll consider the *multiples* approach where appropriate. Thanks Jon.

Comment: This is now available in C# 7 per Jon's prediction. See "Literal Improvements" in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/

Comment: Hey Jon, it looks odd when your answer is outdated, you know what I mean? C# team turned your _maybe_ into reality, so maybe it's time your answer is updated?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ: I'll edit this one, but I don't have a policy of going over all my answers every time there's a new language release to check... I'd have no time to do anything else.

Comment: It's perfectly fine, and I get that completely. After all it is _your_ policy! I could have edited it myself, but then I thought it would be even more odd of me editing _your_ answer! So I nudged you instead ;-)

Comment: Jon mentions that there is no validation that you put the underscores in the right place, and he is right. But that is because "right" is context-sensitive. For example, I needed to write a script that generated random 16 digit numbers, and rather than put my underscores in the thousands place, I put them after every 4: 1000_0000_0000_0000. Made the code more readable.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can do this with C # 7.0 as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476056/what-do-the-underscores-mean-in-a-numeric-literal-in-c/43476057#43476057)

```
public const long BillionsAndBillions = 100_000_000_000;
```