# long integer literals

Tags: c#, .net

I had to deal with the code that does calculation with big number e.g.

```
long foo = 6235449243234;
```

This is hard to tell what is the order of magnitude. I'd like to write it

```
long foo = 6_235_449_243_234;
```

Or

```
long foo = @6 235 449 243 234;
```

But C# doesn't have these features. How to make number literals more readable?

Comment it

```
long foo = 6235449243234; // 6 23...
```

Convert it from string

```
long foo = LiteralConverter.toLong(@"6_235_449_243_234");
int mask = LiteralConverter.toInt("b0111_0000_0100_0000");
```

Any other options?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I declare constant integers with a thousands separator in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488989/can-i-declare-constant-integers-with-a-thousands-separator-in-c)

Comment: In the `LiteralConverter.toLong` example, the `@` is not necessary.

Comment: The language should just support use of '_' in numeric literals.  I don't see any reason why the parser couldn't support that.

Answer (score 5):

Define named constants for these literals, and use comments to explain what the number represents.

```
class MyClass {
    ///
    /// This constant represents cost of a breakfast in Zimbabwe:
    /// 6,235,449,243,234
    ///
    const long AvgBreakfastPriceZimbabweanDollars = 6235449243234;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Comments every time IMO. Otherwise, you're just making the code bloated and less than optimal:

```
long foo = 6235449243234; // 6,235,449,243,234
```

Answer (score 3):

You could write

```
long lNumber = (long)(6e12 + 235e9 + 449e6 + 243e3 + 234);
```

But that is not really readable either.

For numbers in variables when you are debugging you could write a [debugger visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Comments--and if possible--using `const` or `static readonly` values so that you are only declaring/commenting the number in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Another (unrecommended) way of doing it:

```
static long Parse(params int[] parts)
{
    long num = 0;
    foreach (int part in parts)
        num = num * 1000 + part;
    return num;
}

long foo = Parse(6,235,449,243,234);
```

Comment: very clever (outside the box)