# What do the underscores mean in a numeric literal in C#?

Tags: c#

In the code below what is the significance of underscores:

```
public const long BillionsAndBillions = 100_000_000_000;
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This is a new feature of C# 7.0 and it is known as *digit separator*. The intent is to provide **better and easier readability**. It is mostly useful when writing numbers that are very long and hard to read in source code. For example:

```
long hardToRead = 9000000000000000000; 

// With underscores
long easyToRead = 90000_00000_00000_0000;
```

It is totally up to the programmer on where to place the underscore. For example, you may have a weird scenario like this:

```
var weird = 1_00_0_0_000_0000000_0000;  
public const decimal GoldenRatio = 1.618_033_988_749_894_848_204_586_834_365_638_117_720M;
```

---

**Some Notes**

As soon as you compile your code, the compiler removes the underscores so this is just for code readability. So the output of this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    long easyToRead = 90000_00000_00000_0000;
    Console.WriteLine(easyToRead);
}
```

will be (notice no underscores):

```
9000000000000000000
```

[Demo in DotNet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IvVbt8)

Here is a [discussion about this feature](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/216) when it was requested if you are interested. Some people wanted the separator to be *blank* spaces, but looks like the C# team went with *underscores*.

Comment: Stack Overflow [has always explicitly encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) answering your own question. You shouldn't downvote anyone for doing so unless their answer is bad.

Comment: Nice explanation!