# c# readbility of numbers in the editor

Tags: c#

I know I've seen this somewhere, but isn't there some syntax for allowing me to put spaces (or some other formatting) in a large in my code so that large numbers are more readable?

```
var t = 1234567;
```

Could be entered in the editor as:

```
var t = 1 234 567;
```

For the life of me I can't find it.

TIA...

Comment: You're thinking of the underscore (`_`). [It's only available in C# 7 and later.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476056/what-do-the-underscores-mean-in-a-numeric-literal-in-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Starting in C# 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#numeric-literal-syntax-improvements) you can use underscores in the numbers as separators.

```
var t = 1_234_567;
```

Comment: I'm so excited to see how that last sentence ends!!  ;)

Comment: @RufusL ha! Not sure where I was going there with that... removed.