# When i use thread - CPU usage is 100%

Tags: c#

I try to download many html pages using code bellow but when i ran multithreading my CPU is 100% usage

```
using System.Net;
Thread thread = new Thread(t =>    
{
      while(true)
      {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient ()) //
        {
         client.DownloadFile("http://dir.com/page.html", @"C:\localfile.html");
         string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://dir.com/page.html");
        }
      }
})
{ 
    IsBackground = true 
};
thread.Start();
```

Should i use `ThreadPool`

Comment: Why didn't use webclient.downloadfileasync? and why you need endless loop?

Comment: You're not downloading _many_ html pages, but only one. You're doing it in a tight loop so no wonder you're up to 100% when you reach the number of threads that equals your number of (v)cores.

Comment: But when i switch pages after few seconds my CPU goes 100%

Comment: Use async/await and let the framework manage this for you. You don't care if it runs in a new thread or not, you only care that its not blocking thus async/await is the best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `while(true)` without any sleeping in between. The thread will keep running and will consume a lot of CPU power. (And to be honest, the page will not change every 2 ms. You are downloading the same page over and over again.)

You should have some kind of throttling, like a `Thread.Sleep`:

```
while(true)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient ()) //
    {
        string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://dir.com/page.html");

        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\localfile.html", htmlCode);
    }

    Thread.Sleep(60_000); // sleep for 60 seconds.
}
```

Comment: Why `60_000` intead `60000`, is it misspelling or some magic I dont know?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476056/what-do-the-underscores-mean-in-a-numeric-literal-in-c

Comment: Yes, it is a thousand separator. @RandRandom