Windows Service in C#: Threads not starting in Release mode, but working fine in Debug mode
I have a Windows Service written in C# that runs perfectly in Debug mode, but when I build and run it in Release mode, the threads I start (AcceptTCPClient, TCPSender, and SyncMonitorOpenWindows) do not seem to execute. The service itself starts (confirmed via Event Log), but none of the threads seem to be running.
Here’s a snippet of my code:
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        string source = "MyRemoteAgent";
        _serviceIsRunning = true;
        JsonFileManager.ClearJsonFile();

        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(source))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, "Application");
        }

        EventLog.WriteEntry(source, "MyRemoteAgent started.");

        // Starting threads
        new Thread(AcceptTCPClient).Start();
        new Thread(TCPSender).Start();
        new Thread(SyncMonitorOpenWindows).Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry(source, $"Error in OnStart: {ex.Message}", EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }
}

In Debug mode, the service works as expected and all three threads run without any issues.
In Release mode, the service starts (verified via Event Log), but the threads do not seem to execute.
No exceptions are caught in the catch block.
How can I debug this issue in Release mode? Is there a better approach to starting threads in a Windows Service in C#?
What I have tried:

Added additional logging to check if the threads are starting, but no logs appear in Release mode.
Disabled compiler optimizations for the Release configuration, but the issue persists.
Replaced new Thread().Start() with Task.Run(), but the behavior is the same.
Verified that all dependencies are present in the Release folder.
Added Thread.Sleep() after starting the threads to give them time to initialize, but this did not help.

private void AcceptTCPClient()
{
    try
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 6357);
        listener.Start();
        JsonFileManager.InitializeJsonFile();

        while (_serviceIsRunning)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            ServiceProcess serviceProcess = new ServiceProcess(_commandsToSend);
            Client client = new Client(tcpClient, serviceProcess);
            client.AddConnection();
        }

        listener.Stop();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("MyRemoteAgent", $"Error in AcceptTCPClient: {ex.Message}", EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }
}


The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73806343/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/76458119/10024425
