# How to write number literals with thousands separators?

Tags: c#, numbers, separator

Can we use commas in C# as a number separator (e.g., for integer, decimal, double) to separate thousands?

Something like:

```
int million = 1,000,000; // <-- doesn't compile
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488989/can-i-declare-constant-integers-with-a-thousands-separator-in-c just sayin

Comment: @TheGeneral, huh, I searched for some time for an answer after stumbling this and all I could find were questions related to string formatting with commas. Anyway, my self-answer has quite more detailed info regarding this feature, so I think it's worth its own place.

Comment: Yes your self answer is quite good and detailed, however your question is one of many duplicates, usually you would add your great answer to the existing duplicate

Comment: @TheGeneral would have, if only it came up in Google :) I'll close as duplicate, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Although we can't use commas, we can use the underscore digit separator:

- Beginning in C# 7.0, `_` digit separators are permitted *between* the digits of a literal.
- The digit separator can also be used on the right side of the decimal point of decimal, float, and double types as well.
- Beginning in C# 7.2, separators are also permitted *before* the first significant digit of a **binary or hexadecimal** literal, after the prefix (Prefix is `0x` for hex, `0b` for binary. Note that binary literals were added in C# 7.0).
- The digit separator can appear anywhere in the constant. For base 10 numbers, it is common to use it as a thousands separator.

```
    1_2_3    // permitted in C# 7.0 and later
    6.022_140 // permitted in C# 7.0 and later
    1_000.111_1e-1_000 // permitted in C# 7.0 and later
    1_2__3___4____5_____6______7_______8________9  // permitted in C# 7.0 and later, though weird :)
    0x1_2_3  // permitted in C# 7.0 and later
    0b101    // binary literals added in C# 7.0
    0b1_0_1  // permitted in C# 7.0 and later

    // in C# 7.2, _ is permitted after the `0x` or `0b`
    0x_1_2   // permitted in C# 7.2 and later
    0b_1_0_1 // permitted in C# 7.2 and later
```

Further reading:

1. [Official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#numeric-literal-syntax-improvements)
2. [C# 7.0 proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.0/digit-separators)
3. [C# 7.2 proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.2/leading-separator)

Comment: ohhh its a self answer

Comment: *asked 10 mins ago*, *answered 10 mins ago* >> You have solved your own problem pretty quickly ...

Comment: @PeterCsala, as TheGeneral noted, it's a self answer. Also see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69009508/how-to-write-number-literals-with-thousands-separators/69009509?noredirect=1#comment121964936_69009508) above.

Comment: @PeterCsala Nothing wrong with documenting a question and answer to help others.